# Spring Roo 1.3.2 And Java 8

Tags: java, junit, java-8, spring-roo

I want to start my ROO Project in java 8. I configured the eclipse with java compile 8 and it started very well. 
I use Spring 4.1.7, junit 4.12 and aspectj version is 1.8.6.

I have just a problem: junit test doesn't work.

Any suggestions?

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:109)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:307)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:211)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:284)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to read candidate component class: file [/home/flavio/workspace/OK6x3/target/test-classes/it/stasbranger/okseixtre/domain/MessaggioIntegrationTest_Roo_IntegrationTest.class]; nested exception is org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: ASM ClassReader failed to parse class file - probably due to a new Java class file version that isn't supported yet: file [/home/flavio/workspace/OK6x3/target/test-classes/it/stasbranger/okseixtre/domain/MessaggioIntegrationTest_Roo_IntegrationTest.class]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
Offending resource: file [/home/flavio/workspace/OK6x3/target/classes/META-INF/spring/applicationContext-jpa.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to read candidate component class: file [/home/flavio/workspace/OK6x3/target/test-classes/it/stasbranger/okseixtre/domain/MessaggioIntegrationTest_Roo_IntegrationTest.class]; nested exception is org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: ASM ClassReader failed to parse class file - probably due to a new Java class file version that isn't supported yet: file [/home/flavio/workspace/OK6x3/target/test-classes/it/stasbranger/okseixtre/domain/MessaggioIntegrationTest_Roo_IntegrationTest.class]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:68)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:85)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:76)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryBeanDefinitionParser.handleError(RepositoryBeanDefinitionParser.java:84)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryBeanDefinitionParser.parse(RepositoryBeanDefinitionParser.java:77)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport.parse(NamespaceHandlerSupport.java:73)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1438)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1428)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:139)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:493)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:390)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:243)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:233)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:117)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:100)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:248)
    at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:64)
    at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:91)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to read candidate component class: file [/home/flavio/workspace/OK6x3/target/test-classes/it/stasbranger/okseixtre/domain/MessaggioIntegrationTest_Roo_IntegrationTest.class]; nested exception is org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: ASM ClassReader failed to parse class file - probably due to a new Java class file version that isn't supported yet: file [/home/flavio/workspace/OK6x3/target/test-classes/it/stasbranger/okseixtre/domain/MessaggioIntegrationTest_Roo_IntegrationTest.class]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.findCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:290)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationSourceSupport.getCandidates(RepositoryConfigurationSourceSupport.java:68)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport.getRepositoryConfigurations(RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport.java:53)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryBeanDefinitionParser.parse(RepositoryBeanDefinitionParser.java:69)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: ASM ClassReader failed to parse class file - probably due to a new Java class file version that isn't supported yet: file [/home/flavio/workspace/OK6x3/target/test-classes/it/stasbranger/okseixtre/domain/MessaggioIntegrationTest_Roo_IntegrationTest.class]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:56)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:80)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.CachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(CachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:102)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.findCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:266)
    ... 49 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:53)
    ... 52 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring Roo 1.3.2 generates Spring 3.x application. As [explains this SO response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22527057/2295657) the exception that you get should be produced by use Spring 3. Use `mvn dependecy:tree` or eclipse *dependencies* tab of the pom-file editor to check that all your spring dependencies points to 4.x version (Almost sure you problem is located in test-scope dependencies)

Good luck!