# Tomcat 7 with MySQL connector: ASM ClassReader failed to parse class file

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat7, java-7

I downloaded the latest MySQL connector mysql-connector-java-5.1.37.zip from  https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/.

Tomcat is throwing "ASM ClassReader failed to parse class file - probably d
    e to a new Java class file version that isn't supported yet:[]" while starting my webapp. I tried running with JDK 7 and 8. Search results indicate the error may occur if the jar was built for JDK 8, not with JDK 7 compile level.

[Java 1.8 ASM ClassReader failed to parse class file - probably due to a new Java class file version that isn't supported yet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22526695/java-1-8-asm-classreader-failed-to-parse-class-file-probably-due-to-a-new-java)

Is there another MySQL connector jar I should use? Other workarounds?
(The webapp also uses Spring 3.2.4)

```
C:/servers/apache-tomcat-7.0.65/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.37-bin.jar!/com/mysql/jdbc/JDBC42CallableStatement.class];
nested exception is org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: ASM ClassReader failed to parse class file - probably d
e to a new Java class file version that isn't supported yet: URL [jar:file:/C:/servers/apache-tomcat-7.0.65/lib/mysql-c
nnector-java-5.1.37-bin.jar!/com/mysql/jdbc/JDBC42CallableStatement.class]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgume
tException
       at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.findCandidateComponents(Cl
ssPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:290)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switching to mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar from the "Previous GA" section solved the issue. 
https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/5.0.html