# Spring Application context not found

Tags: java, spring, maven, vaadin

I'm having an issue with reading the application context of my application. I'm doing experiments with [Vaadin](https://vaadin.com/home). My configuration class, which is annotated in a way I've used before in other projects and always works is annotated with:

```
@ImportResource("classpath:applicationContext.xml")
```

What makes this so odd is that no matter what I  do, even using it to explicitly find the file, for example:

```
@ImportResource("/tmp/classpath:applicationContext.xml")
```

It still does not work!
I'm using Spring 3 at the moment (for historical reasons...)

> 2016/05/17 13:39 ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext:319 - Context
>   initialization failed  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
>           at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.(Unknown Source)
>           at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.(Unknown Source)
>           at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.(Unknown Source)
>           at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.(SimpleMetadataReader.java:52)
>           at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:80)
>           at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.CachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(CachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:102)
>           at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:76)
>           at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassUtils.checkConfigurationClassCandidate(ConfigurationClassUtils.java:70)
>           at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:253)
>           at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:223)
>           at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:630)
>           at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:461)
>           at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389)
>           at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294)
>           at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:782)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:424)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:774)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:249)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1242)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:717)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:494)
>           at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.JettyWebAppContext.doStart(JettyWebAppContext.java:298)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:229)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:172)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:229)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:95)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:282)
>           at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.JettyServer.doStart(JettyServer.java:65)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
>           at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.startJetty(AbstractJettyMojo.java:520)
>           at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.execute(AbstractJettyMojo.java:365)
>           at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.JettyRunMojo.execute(JettyRunMojo.java:523)
>           at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
>           at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
>           at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
>           at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
>           at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
>           at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
>           at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>           at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
>           at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
>           at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
>           at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)

Comment: It seems like the configuration needs to be done differently. Have you looked into this: https://vaadin.com/wiki?p_p_id=36&p_p_lifecycle=0&p_p_state=normal&p_p_mode=view&p_p_col_id=row-1&p_p_col_pos=2&p_p_col_count=4&_36_struts_action=%2Fwiki%2Fview&p_r_p_185834411_nodeName=vaadin.com+wiki&p_r_p_185834411_title=I+b+-+Getting+started+with+Vaadin+Spring+without+Spring+Boot ?

Comment: @LoreV I've just tested with the tutorial of the page. I get exactly the same Exception still. What I am trying to do is to keep Spring the way it is and integrate it with vaadin and what's so odd as well is that I can get this exception if I just remove the application context file in other working applications. For this one, it's just a very strange behaviour.

Comment: Can you please share a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) on github or a similar service? This should make it easier to spot anything you may have overlooked

Comment: @Morfic I can't show anything that is directly related to the application. Only generic stuff. I guess the best way to analise it would be to see if you know of any other case where this would happen and maybe ask a question about it. I can tell you where the annotations have been declared but that's as far as I can go in showing code. anyhow...thanks in advance!

Comment: That is understandable and perfectly fine. After all, a SSCCE should be a simple version of your app, stripped of any sensitive information and reduced to only the few classes which make it reproducible. Thus, what we're asking here is, start from scratch and create some dummy classes and the spring context which get you the same exception, and share that with us. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of research we finally found what was going on. Very tricky this one but it makes sense:

[Java 1.8 ASM ClassReader failed to parse class file - probably due to a new Java class file version that isn't supported yet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22526695/java-1-8-asm-classreader-failed-to-parse-class-file-probably-due-to-a-new-java)

Essentially the new ASM is not reading classes the same way as it used to, and Spring 3 is reading them with the old ASM compatibility. This results in that I can run the application in Java 8 only if I change to Spring 4. Spring does guarantee compatibility between Spring 4 and any old java version since Java 6:

https://spring.io/blog/2015/04/03/how-spring-achieves-compatibility-with-java-6-7-and-8

The oposite is not true which means that I cannot run Spring 3 with Java 8, and so we now have a good migration work to do :).