# JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered (Tomcat 7)

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, jdbc

I've added a customized annotation in our existing maven project. It's for a date validation: `@PresentOrFuture`.

Here's the PresentOrFuture.java annotation:

```
@Target({ ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.PARAMETER })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = PresentOrFutureValidator.class)
@Documented
public @interface PresentOrFuture {
    String message() default "{PresentOrFuture.message}";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

And here's the `PresentOrFutureValidator.java` class:

```
public class PresentOrFutureValidator
    implements ConstraintValidator<PresentOrFuture, Date> {

    public final void initialize(final PresentOrFuture annotation) {}

    public final boolean isValid(final Date value,
        final ConstraintValidatorContext context) {

        // Only use the date for comparison
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(); 
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

        Date today = calendar.getTime();

        // Your date must be after today or today (== not before today)
        return !value.before(today) || value.after(today);

    }
}
```

And when I try to **mvn tomcat7:run** it, I keep getting this error:

```
Nov 11, 2016 5:44:10 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to read candidate component class: file [C:\Palmus-HACMS\ssi-hms\target\classes\ph\com\smesoft\hms\domain\PresentOrFuture.class]; nested exception is org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: ASM ClassReader failed to parse class file - probably due to a new Java class file version that isn't supported yet: class path resource [java/lang/annotation/Annotation.class]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
Offending resource: file [C:\Palmus-HACMS\ssi-hms\target\classes\META-INF\spring\applicationContext-jpa.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to read candidate component class: file [C:\Palmus-HACMS\ssi-hms\target\classes\ph\com\smesoft\hms\domain\PresentOrFuture.class]; nested exception is org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: ASM ClassReader failed to parse class file - probably due to a new Java class file version that isn't supported yet: class path resource [java/lang/annotation/Annotation.class]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:68)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:85)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:76)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryBeanDefinitionParser.handleError(RepositoryBeanDefinitionParser.java:84)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryBeanDefinitionParser.parse(RepositoryBeanDefinitionParser.java:77)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport.parse(NamespaceHandlerSupport.java:73)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1438)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1428)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:195)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:139)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:108)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:493)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:390)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:451)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:410)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5017)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5531)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1574)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1564)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to read candidate component class: file [C:\Palmus-HACMS\ssi-hms\target\classes\ph\com\smesoft\hms\domain\PresentOrFuture.class]; nested exception is org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: ASM ClassReader failed to parse class file - probably due to a new Java class file version that isn't supported yet: class path resource [java/lang/annotation/Annotation.class]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.findCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:290)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationSourceSupport.getCandidates(RepositoryConfigurationSourceSupport.java:68)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport.getRepositoryConfigurations(RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport.java:53)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryBeanDefinitionParser.parse(RepositoryBeanDefinitionParser.java:69)
        ... 30 more
Caused by: org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: ASM ClassReader failed to parse class file - probably due to a new Java class file version that isn't supported yet: class path resource [java/lang/annotation/Annotation.class]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:56)
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:80)
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.CachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(CachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:102)
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:76)
        at org.springframework.core.type.filter.AbstractTypeHierarchyTraversingFilter.match(AbstractTypeHierarchyTraversingFilter.java:105)
        at org.springframework.core.type.filter.AbstractTypeHierarchyTraversingFilter.match(AbstractTypeHierarchyTraversingFilter.java:95)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.isCandidateComponent(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:333)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.findCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:267)
        ... 33 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:53)
        ... 40 more

Nov 11, 2016 5:44:10 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
Nov 11, 2016 5:44:10 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/hms] startup failed due to previous errors
Nov 11, 2016 5:44:10 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Nov 11, 2016 5:44:10 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStop
SEVERE: Exception sending context destroyed event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.IllegalStateException: BeanFactory not initialized or already closed - call 'refresh' before accessing beans via the ApplicationContext
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.getBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:171)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1090)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1064)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1010)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.closeWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:586)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(ContextLoaderListener.java:143)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:5064)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5726)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:160)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1574)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1564)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Nov 11, 2016 5:44:10 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesJdbc
SEVERE: The web application [/hms] registered the JDBC driver [org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
Nov 11, 2016 5:44:10 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
```

I'm just a newbie. And I tried some solutions that I saw but it doesn't work for me, I hope someone can help me. Thank you.

Comment: The error message about the JDBC driver is not relevant here: it's a knock-on effect of the other errors you have.  Which version of Java are you using?  Which version of Spring are you using?  Does [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22526695/java-1-8-asm-classreader-failed-to-parse-class-file-probably-due-to-a-new-java) help?

Comment: I'm using Java Version 1.6 & Spring Version 3.2.8.RELEASE Sir.

Comment: The second answer to the question I linked to suggests that there's a bug in Spring 3.2.8, which looks a lot like what you're hitting.  Could you try upgrading to a later version of Spring 3.2?

Comment: I tried to upgrade my spring version to 4.3.4.RELEASE Sir, but when ever I run it I get this error: "Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:aspectj-maven-plugin:1.4:compile (default) on project hms: Compiler errors: error can't determine superclass of missing type org.springframework.cache.jcache.interceptor.JCacheAspectSupport when batch building BuildConfig[null]"

Comment: I said upgrade to a later version of Spring 3.2, such as 3.2.17.  I did not say upgrade to Spring 4.

Comment: @LukeWoodward It work Sir! Thank you. :)