# ASM ClassReader failed to parse class file on Spring 4.3.1.RELEASE

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, aspectj

While migrating a Java Spring application from Java 1.6 to Java 1.8 I got  on an AspectJ class the following error:

```
ASM ClassReader failed to parse class file - probably due to a new Java class file version that isn't supported yet
```

Even if [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22526695/java-1-8-asm-classreader-failed-to-parse-class-file-probably-due-to-a-new-java) says the opposite, I still have a problem.

I use:

1. Java 8
2. AspectJ 1.8.9 (also tryed with 1.8.10, same error)
3. Tomcat 8
4. Spring 4.3.1

What am I missing?

Comment: How about providing an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Being able to reproduce your problem would be the first step in solving it.

Comment: clean the tomcat8 directory and try again