# Failed to execute goal org.apache.uima:ruta-maven-plugin:2.6.1 generate

Tags: uima, ruta

Can no longer build my application due to an issue with a dependent class of ruta-maven-plugin:2.6.1. I've tried to use multiple version of ASM including 5.0.2 and 6.2. These version are dependencies of Apache Tika 1.17/18/19.

Here is the full build failure message:

Failed to execute goal org.apache.uima:ruta-maven-plugin:2.6.1:generate (default) on project DAnE-Pipeline: Execution default of goal org.apache.uima:ruta-maven-plugin:2.6.1:generate failed: Failed to read candidate component class: URL [jar:file:/home/fm/.m2/repository/org/apache/uima/ruta-core/2.6.1/ruta-core-2.6.1.jar!/org/apache/uima/ruta/resource/TrieXMLEventHandler.class]; nested exception is org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: ASM ClassReader failed to parse class file - probably due to a new Java class file version that isn't supported yet: class path resource [org/xml/sax/helpers/DefaultHandler.class]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException -> [Help 1]

I feel like I've tried everything. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Have you seen this StackOverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22526695/java-1-8-asm-classreader-failed-to-parse-class-file-probably-due-to-a-new-java). You could try to upgrade the spring version in the scope of the plugin.

Comment: I tried to upgrade to various Spring versions, but nothing helped. I also tried backing out of Tika 1.19 to 1.17 because 1.19 has uimaFit locked to 2.2.0. Should I attempt to build Ruta Core to Java 1.8?

Comment: Did you manually compile Ruta or obtain it from Maven Central?

Comment: I get it from Maven Central

Answer (score 1):

I re-read Peter's suggestion above. I was adding a newer Spring dependency in my project, but not in the "scope of the plugin". Once I created the Spring dependencies there, it worked! Thanks, Peter.