# Need help fixing 'ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException'

Tags: java, arrays, spring, jsp, indexoutofboundsexception

As described in the title i get `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` when i start my Tomcat 7 with NetBeans 8.2.

I've tried troubleshooting with those two threads without any success:

[ArrayOutOfBoundsException: asm.ClassReader.readClass(Unknown Source)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35046404/arrayoutofboundsexception-asm-classreader-readclassunknown-source)

[Failed to load ApplicationContext caused by ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in ClassReader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17563149/failed-to-load-applicationcontext-caused-by-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-in-cl)

The exception seems to be caused by `org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.readClass`
or `DienststellenController.class`

```
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 52264
at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.readClass(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)

[Path\DienststellenController.class]; nested exception is 
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 52264
```

When i run my project with those four lines commented out, it works like a charm without any exceptions:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/query", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView queryGet(HttpServletRequest request) {
    logger.debug("Received request to show a input form page");
    List<Person> personListe = personDao.getPersonalStamm();
    //List<String> ls = new ArrayList<>();
    Dienststelle d = (Dienststelle) request.getSession().getAttribute("dienststelle");
        if (d == null) {
        d = new Dienststelle();
    }
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("phonebook/dienststelle/query", "dienststelle", d);
    //personListe.forEach((p) -> {
    //    ls.add(p.getAnzeige());
    //});
    mv.addObject("person", personListe);
    return mv;
}
```

Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/query", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView queryGet(HttpServletRequest request) {
    logger.debug("Received request to show a input form page");
    List<Person> personListe = personDao.getPersonalStamm();
    List<String> ls = new ArrayList<>();
    Dienststelle d = (Dienststelle) request.getSession().getAttribute("dienststelle");
        if (d == null) {
        d = new Dienststelle();
    }
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("phonebook/dienststelle/query", "dienststelle", d);
    personListe.forEach((p) -> {
        ls.add(p.getAnzeige());
    });
    mv.addObject("person", ls);
    return mv;
}
```

Method from dao class

```
@Override
public List<Person> getPersonalStamm() {
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM personalDB.personalstamm";
    RowMapper<Person> rm = ParameterizedBeanPropertyRowMapper.newInstance(Person.class);
    List<Person> personen = (List<Person>) getJdbcTemplate().query(sql, rm);
    return personen;
}
```

jsp page

```
    <tr>
        <td><label>Vorgesetzter</label></td>
        <td>
            <form:select path="verantwortlich" maxlength="11" >
                <form:option value="0" label="-"/>
                <form:options items='${person}' itemValue='name' itemLabel='name' />
            </form:select>                
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: where do you get ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException?

Comment: `personListe.forEach((p) -> {
        ls.add(p.getAnzeige());
    });` This line of code is what causes the exception. It takes first name and last name out of the object p via getter and puts it into the ArrayList<String> ls. I just cant see what i'm doing wrong here.

Comment: Is it possible that JSP accesses the ArrayList at index 1 instead of 0?

Comment: can you show the full stack?  you have no direct interaction with an array.

Comment: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException happens when i start Tomcat 7. I've added a pastebin containing the log.

Comment: @Taylor Adding entries into an Array doesn't count as interaction? Please excuse me if this sounds like a stupid question.

Comment: As far as I can tell, you're adding to an `ArrayList`, which is very different from an array.

Comment: After reading your pastebin, this has nothing to do with the code you indicated.  The exception is rooted in `org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.readClass`. This probably answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35046404/arrayoutofboundsexception-asm-classreader-readclassunknown-source

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Failed to load ApplicationContext caused by ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in ClassReader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17563149/failed-to-load-applicationcontext-caused-by-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-in-cl)

Comment: I've edited the question to match moderation guidelines. Sadly, those two threads didn't answer my questions. @Taylor

Comment: Your problem is you're using a dependency that doesn't align with your jdk version.